# Issue for Retrieving of Special Characters from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I display the values into GridView and it displays well. but when I put a code on `OnSelectedIndexChanged` with this code:

```
City = GeneralInfoData.SelectedRow.Cells[13].Text.ToString();
```

and put the value on a textbox.

The value

```
Dasmariñas
```

becomes

```
Dasmari&#241;as
```

[image: it saves well in database]

Comment: `the retrieved value becomes "&# 241;"` How did you confirm that? In HTML that you generated? In the Watch Window? Somewhere else?

Comment: It sounds far more likely that there is a problem with the process between generating the data and it ending up in your database, or with how you're rendering it once it comes out of your database. As @mjwills asked, please provide an [mcve].

Comment: Without providing a [mcve], we can't assist you. **This must include the actual code you are using to read from the database.**

Comment: Are you using a template column or data bound column? With `GeneralInfoData.SelectedRow.Cells[13]` you are dealing with 2nd hand data. It has been changed by the gridview to encode special characters. You would be better off dealing with the data that has been retrieved, directly.

Comment: hi can you tell me the column type which you are using to store this "Dasmariñas" value @bograt

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing that value as part of some HTML in your asp.net application, then there's nothing wrong: `&#241;` is the HTML code to represent the 'n tilde' character as you can see here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp

Answer (score 0):

N with a Tilde comes under **ISO-8859-1** encoding.

You need to modify your `web.config` like below:

```
<system.web> 
<globalization responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" /> 
</system.web>
```

Following page will provide an interesting read:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: N with a tilde comes under lots of encodings